# Dynamic variable/local data name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have several local data variables named `icon1Loading`, `icon2Loading`, etc. How can I call variables dynamically to change their value?

```
data(){
  return {
    icon1Loading: false,
    icon2Loading: false
  }
}

changeLoadingState(iconNumber){
  this.icon${iconNumber}Loading = true
}
```

Comment: Are those supposed to be variables or object properties? `:` is for properties.

Comment: These are vue data options https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: Anyway, if you access them as properties of `this`, the question I linked to shows how to do it.